# Google map loads only if I resize the browser window

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I´m working on a google maps implementation and it works fine so far. To try things and play around with it I made an extra file for that.

Here you can checkout the map: [Google maps file](http://www.fabiansquinobal.com/geo.html)

I have everything ready in that file and I want to implement that to my website. I took the code and copied it to my "main-file".

Now, the google-map won´t load in the first place, only if I resize the browser or write something in the text field.

The browser doesn´t give me any errors back.

```
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURAPIKEY&callback=initMap&language=de">
```

This Code-Sample is on the end of my `<body>`-tag. I know that google-map needs to load async, but I´m not realy sure what it is, because - I´m a beginner...

Can anyone give me a hint why the map is acting like that?

All javascript-files that are needed are implemented.

Comment: You are required to post a complete but minimal example of your problem markup or code here within your question: [mcve]

Comment: add your code here

Comment: The code is 700 lines long. What should I post if the browser doesen´t give me any errors back? Do you want the full file?

Comment: The thing is, that everything is working fine. Only the browser needs to "reinject?" - because if i resize the window, the google map appears. Is that a "sync"-problem?

Answer (score 0):

Google maps seem to be showing without resizing the window though.

If it's not showing, try adding "resize" event trigger on map load. It is the same event for window resizing.

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('newjobmap'), options);
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
}
```

Comment: Hi Thu Sama, thanks for your answer. Sadly it didn´t work.

Comment: Even if I give the div a fixed height and width the map won´t load.

Comment: Your link http://www.fabiansquinobal.com/geo.html is working fine. And I can't reproduce the bug. So it is hard for me to see what's the problem. It would be helpful to provide some screenshot or example 'not working' code.